# why the button 'U' creates new file in VS code?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

whenever I press the letter/button 'U' during coding in vs code, it automatically creates a new file.

the button 'u' is working as a shortcut key to create a new file in vs code.

lastly, if I copy/paste the letter 'u' in my code then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your keybinds are messed up, You could try to check here, see if this works.
[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#:~:text=All%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20in%20VS,This%20will%20open%20your%20keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#:%7E:text=All%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20in%20VS,This%20will%20open%20your%20keybindings).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should be due to some extensions you installed, or some misoperation that led to the modification of shortcut keys.

[image]

Find the keyboard shortcut and search for "creat: new file"

[image]